# Preferred way to build multiple projects with Jenkins, CMake and pkg-config?

Tags: linux, jenkins, cmake, pkg-config

I am developing two libraries A and B with B depending on A, both managed in their own Git repositories. The libraries are built with CMake and installed in standard UNIX directories. During installation a `.pc` file is also installed that is used by `pkg-config`. Library B uses `pkg-config` to find library A, therefore it is necessary that either library A is installed system-wide with `make install` or the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` is set to the appropriate directory.

Now, I use Jenkins to build library A on a remote machine. Unfortunately, library B cannot be built because the dependency is not met (`pkg-config` cannot find library A). Setting the paths in a pre-build step is not working because the commands are run in its own shell.

The questions are

- Can I somehow `make install` library A? Or,
- can I somehow point CMake to `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/libA/install_dir/lib`?
- Is there a better way to build projects with inter-dependent libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using artifacts, as suggested by user1013341, is one of the steps that was needed to this problem. But to get it working with `pkg-config` we have to do a little bit more:

1. I setup library A's `CMakeLists.txt` to produce a tarball with `make package_source`.
2. After a successful build of library A, Jenkins create this tarball and stores it as an artifact.
3. library B uses the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to get the tarball and untars it. Inside of the tarball there is still built project and the `.pc` file pointing to the install location of library A.
4. In the next build step, I use the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to set the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` and the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the untarred library A.
5. Last but not least, the normal CMake build process can be started and the correct paths are picked up according to the environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions in order:

To make install library A - You can configure the Jenkins job that builds library A to archive the library as a build artefact. Then the job to build library B can download the artefact from Jenkins at the start of the run – e.g.  http:///job/libA/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/ 
Once the library B job has collected library A it can then be installed and used.

Configuring Cmake – I don't know enough about cmake so I'm afraid I can't answer that.

Is there a better way – Possibly using Rake, we use it to control a build chain with lot's of dependencies. Although I'm not sure how well it would work if library A has to be built on a remote machine. Things might be simpler to manage if both libraries are build on the same machine.

Comment: Actually they are built on the same (remote) machine. What I wanted to say is, that Jenkins or CMake might not easily install things because of permissions. Unfortunately, your first answer really doesn't help me, because still library B tries to find library A via `pkg-config`, how could "downloading" an artifact help here?

Comment: Oh ok, when you said that you used jenkins to build library A on a remote machine I assumed that meant that the two libraries were built on different machines. If you are having trouble installing the build library because of permissions, would you be able to set up a chroot to build in? Then you shoud be able to install the libraries without permission issues, or overwriting other software on the build machine.

Comment: This solution is bad because the documentation says artifacts should be no larger than 100MB. When you compile multiple libraries with debug symbols, that can easily be surpassed.